# Functional group for glycine that had being titrated (i) HCl (ii)NaOH

Tags: experimental-chemistry, ph, titration, amino-acids

i am kinda confused with this question. They asked for the functional group of (i) glycine hydrochloride  (ii) glycine that titrated with NaOH. I did take a look many times especially for glycine hydrochloride. But the R-group is still the same, that is H, not the NH3+ Cl- (if I'm not mistaken, NH2 is amino group).

Oh, and when they mentioned glycine species from both of these mixtures, what did they mean by it?

Please enlighten me since I am totally lost here.

Answer (score 0):

Glycine:
$$\ce{NH3^{+}-CH2-COO- + OH- -> NH2-CH2-COO- + H2O}$$

Glycine hydrochloride:
$$\ce{NH3^{+}-CH2-COOH + 2 OH- -> NH2-CH2-COO- + 2 H2O}$$